# Before and After property for Border styling in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am working on CSS border properties, I have done with border-radius,border,border-width,border-color,border-collapse,border-image,etc. I want my border at the left side of my page as shown in the pic [click here for the image to be shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvGhx.png). Can anyone teach me with this. Thank you

Comment: Where is your tried HTML, Please make a working example

Comment: You might want this : https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_path.asp

Comment: @Lokesh Gupta <div class="profileHeading" style="background: #ecf4f4;border-radius: 13%;">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pseudo elements to get the border same, you can play with properties to know about how it works.

Below i posted an example

```css
.box {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:green;
  position:relative;
}
.box:before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  top:10%;
  transform:rotate(-10deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-10deg);
  left:14px;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  display:block;
  border-top:10px solid green;
  border-bottom:10px solid transparent;
  border-right:10px solid transparent;
  border-left:10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```